# Automate and sync changes to docker image with container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on docker image, the container is using it.

Every time I make changes to the image I need to shut down the container, delete the old image and build a new one,

I have docker on ubuntu digital ocean server.

I tried to put the image files on github and used the repo in docker-compose to reduce build steps.

I need to know if there is a better way to sync the changes with the container.

I also got error when I tried to build image from github:

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /myhome/node/api
COPY ./api /myhome/node/api/
RUN npm install
CMD npm run app
```

docker compose:

```
node-api-a:
    build:
      context: git@github.com:BasselTurky/bluekiwiapp-repo.git#main
      dockerfile: api-image/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY={MYKEY}
```

this is the error:

```
Step 3/5 : COPY ./api /myhome/node/api/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat api: file does not exist
ERROR: Service 'node-api-a' failed to build : Build failed
```

repo directory:

```
bluekiwiapp-repo
  - docker-compose.yml
  - api-image
    - api     < code folder
    - .dockerignore
    - Dockerfile
```

Comment: Are you thinking about CI/CD pipeline? What about github actions or jenkins?

Comment: You can build the new image before you shut down the old container.  You can build the image remotely and `docker push` it to a registry of some sort (Docker Hub, something your cloud provider has, something you run yourself).  If you build the image remotely and use a unique tag per build, you can change the Compose `image:` line (or use an environment variable) to have the new tag, and then run `docker-compose up -d` without manually stopping anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copy Fails**

`api` directory is inside `api-image`, which is not the docker build context in your case. It should include `:<folder>` for docker

```
node-api-a:
    build:
      context: git@github.com:BasselTurky/bluekiwiapp-repo.git#main:api-image
      dockerfile: api-image/Dockerfile
```

Source : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories

**To sync new image changes to the container**, the container has to be recreated with the new image. If using docker-compose you can user `--always-recreate-deps` option

> --always-recreate-deps      Recreate dependent containers. Incompatible with --no-recreate.

Comment: I did as you said but had to remove api-image from ``` dockerfile: api-image/Dockerfile``` 

to ``` dockerfile: Dockerfile``` and add it to context as you did.